# Context.User.Identity.Name returns null in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm setting the forms authentication cookie like this below

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("test", true);`

and when i check if its set it returns null...

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
```

any ideas why this is happening? thanks

Comment: where are you calling that?

Comment: I'm setting the "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("test", true);" in a controller and calling the "Context.User.Identity.Name" from the Layout.cshtml (master page)

Comment: are they in the same request?

Comment: I'm simply returning the controller Login method to a redirect to action.. so yeah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always redirect after setting a forms authentication cookie:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("test", true);    
    return RedirectToAction("FooBar");
}
```

It's only in the subsequent action you are redirecting to that you will get the `User.Identity.Name` being properly initialized. The reason for that is pretty simple: the `User.Identity.Name` property is initialized from the Request cookies (a.k.a incoming cookies) whereas the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` is setting the forms authentication to the response (a.k.a. emitting a cookie) so that on subsequent requests this cookie will be sent in the request.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I'm doing.. see the answer below

Comment: Alright, inside the `Home/Index` action you should be able to retrieve the `User.Identity.Name` successfully. Make sure you have correctly configured forms authentication in your web.config and that cookies are enabled in your browser: `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /></authentication>`.

Comment: Thats what I was missing the web.config configuration.. Thanks a lot mate!!